Extracting individual curves from an image
newbie here with little knowledge on opencv/image-processing with python. I'm trying to extract arrows/curves defined in an image (background - white). So far I tried using contours and a few basic approaches like masks, edge detection etc, but none helped.
Note: the findContours method actually found all the edges but the problem is I couldn't then extract path of each arrows from it.
below are my basic requirements:

Each arrow defines a path (I can color each arrow differently if needed) Note: I created arrows from an online editor (draw.io)
Arrows can cross each others path
Arrow head defines the end of the path

so, as you'd have guessed,  I need to extract x, y co-ordinates for each arrow, from this image. but if I can at least extract each arrows separately, then I'm hoping to use methods like findContours to extract the coordinates.
Adding the image for your reference. 

where do the curves come from?

I created it from draw.io, but there are no requirements as such. [btw, thanks I updated the question]

from draw.io? then you can save/download the editable drawing file and get your curves out of that. problem solved. or make a program with which you can draw your curves (splines, beziers). then you have a description of each curve, by virtue of it having been "drawn" from such control points. -- you seem to think scraping a description of a curve out of a picture is trivial. it's not. it is significant engineering effort.

Try saving a very simple draw.io file in SVG format and inspect that with a text editor.

I understand and thanks. but I'm still curious know if there is a way to do this with opencv or similar frameworks.

@Pravinkumar how would you define the path of the line? As mentioned by Christoph, this involves PhD level work

honestly, no criteria. it is just some random paths

it can be done, and I did that for another question (unanswered because OP seemingly lost interest), because there the curve information didn't exist already: the task was to measure a real world object. I would not say it'd take a PhD (or maybe I should have one...), just a bit of engineering. crossings might require careful treatment though.

oh interesting, could you share the link for the other question that you're talking about?

@ChristophRackwitz given a set of indendent lines, this task gets a bit simpler of course. Once intersections occur (worse if one colour), the definition of which lines is which becomes more than tricky. I think Cris Luengo posted a link to a dissertation specifically about this topic once.
